# 0 users have archaeologist badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I was scrolling through my badges today and noticed that beside the "Archaeologist" badge, it said x0. I checked SO and there was a plausible number beside the same badge but not on Programmers.

Bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not seeing any number beside the badge.

Given that the requirements are:

> Edited **100** posts that were inactive for **6** months

(emphasis mine), and the more ephemeral nature of posts on Programmers as compared to Stack Overflow (for example), I'm not surprised that there are no recipients of this badge. There are only 189 recipients of the badge on Stack Overflow with its 3,000,000+ questions, four year history and many 1,000s of users.

The thing to do is compare the number of "Excavator" badges (Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months) that have been awarded. It's 260 here on programmers compared to 15,244 on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It really should be gold...

Comment: There is no number using the desktop site but there is a 0 on the mobile site. Good answer though, thank you!

Comment: However I still think it is an issue that this badge isn't gold since 0 people have it.

Comment: @AustinHenley - that's a separate question :)

Comment: @AustinHenley well rarity per se is not sufficient to justify the gold status. To me, Archaeologist fits more to the way how silver is defined at ["Legend" section of Badges page](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/badges): "Silver badges are awarded for longer term goals. Silver badges are uncommon, but **definitely attainable** if you’re interested" than to gold: "Gold Badges are rare. You’ll have to actively work toward these. They’re something of an **accomplishment**!"

Comment: @gnat "Gold Badges are rare." Isn't 0 people having it mean it is pretty rare?

Comment: @AustinHenley The number of people who get a particular badge can vary wildly site by site and depends on whether or not people on that site are interested in that particular badge. That's not necessarily a reason to change the colour of the badge. I'd say Archaeologist is definitely attainable here on Programmers... there are plenty of old questions that could use an edit.

Comment: Since it would be easy to game the system and get this badge, I think it's better not to make it gold.

Comment: @AustinHenley rare, yes - but would it make "something of an accomplishment"? with 1000+ edits I easily made on Programmers I really doubt that 100 changes to old messages are a serious accomplishment

Comment: @gnat You deserve a gold star for that BTW.

Comment: @maple_shaft I am sufficiently rewarded looking at score bumps my edits [sometimes do](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/148524/31260 "what a difference a picture makes"). Copy Editor badge is nice, too

Comment: @user281377 Game the system? Take a look at our [editors page](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) (only 22 editors with more than 100 edits), if making archaeologist gold provides an incentive for people to start editing, I'm all for it.